# How to exit from the if condition not in while loop in php?

Tags: php

How to exit from if condition not in while loop ?.when country is match to stored country at that time exit from the if condition not in while loop.

```
    $country = $_POST['Country'] ;
    $sql = "select * from country_details";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
         $AllCountry = $row['CountryName']; 

         if($country==$AllCountry)
         {

            $Last_Insert_Country_Id=$row['CountryId'];
            break;

         }
         else
         {

            $date = date("Y/m/d");
            $sql = "insert into country_details (CountryName,CreatedDate) values ('$country','$date')";
            $query=mysql_query($sql);
            $Last_Insert_Country_Id=mysql_insert_id();
            break;
          }


  }
```

Comment: Try `continue` instead of break

Comment: What do you mean by exit from if condition.Do you want to go tho the next iteration.?

Comment: Intresting after the if/ you do not have any command so i think it's unnecessary to use continue.

Answer (score 1):

When the `if` statements condition is matched, your `break` does nothing but break out of the loop. So by asking "break out of if statement" is redundant. If you want to skip the rest of the loops iteration, use `continue` instead, however it seems unnecessary:

When the if triggers, the else will not. So the iteration will be skipped either way.

Oh, and please sanitize your input. You are vulnerable to SQL injection! MYSQL_* is also deprecated, use MYSQLi_* or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

With **continue** you go to end of your current cycle, and start a new while iteration.

With **break** you exit your current while cycle.